# Internet Service for multiple people

Tags: usa, road-trips, internet, group-travel

How do you provide a decent speed internet connection to multiple devices on a USA road trip? (either on interstates, in campgrounds or hotels)

Four people have at least 2 devices the following (total 11 devices), but up to 5 active at any given time.

- iPhone
- iPad
- iPod
- Laptops (iOS and Win7)

Comment: To clarify, what is the primary intent of your question: do you want to know the name of a US-wide data service provider, or do you want to know how a handful of data connections can be shared between multiple devices? The first one belongs here, the latter belongs to superuser.com and if you say so, I can migrate this question.

Comment: Or do you want to know if there is some kind of device that can provide this?

Answer (score 6):

Use [Mifi](http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/mobilebroadband/?page=products_mifi)

Mifi is a device that able to host a Wifi connection using 3G card.

Small enough to fit in your pocket, but powerful enough to bring the Internet to your whole family wherever your wireless phone goes - no cables required. Just power it on and instantly connect up to five Wi-Fi-enabled devices.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Search for "wifi tethering". There are some apps that turn your phone into a wifi hotspot in android app market, but i have also seen [dedicated devices](http://www.phone-guide-germany.com/3g-modem-routers-ipad-wifi/3506/) who are essentially wifi+3g modem+battery in one box.

see also the section about carrier contracts at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering